# Window isn't rendering properly

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, materials, glass

Using the rendering preview, I get the intended result:

[image]

But upon rendering, the window seems to just be white. I haven't shown the whole render because it will take to long but the colour of the window is the result I'm getting.

[image]

I've removed the world scene, using individual lighting. Here is what outside of the "House" looks like:

[image]

regarding my window, setting I have are:

- Spectacular set to 1
- Sheen Tint to 0.5
- Emission on one with the colour set to black
- Alpha set to 13

Comment: What happens a lot of time is a placeholder in the outliner gets hidden in viewport but is still visible in the render.

Comment: Classic error, thank you issue resolved